# Is Minkowski space a Hilbert space?

Tags: geometry, hilbert-spaces, physics, mathematical-physics, geometric-topology

In other words, is Minkowski space a real or complex inner product space that is also a complete metric space with respect to the distance function induced by the inner product?  I would think that Minkowski space can either be thought of as 2-D complex or 4-D real, do either of these interpretations change whether or not it is a Hilbert space?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526171/is-minkowski-space-not-a-metric-space

Answer (score 6):

A Hilbert space is a real or complex vector space with an inner product which induces a norm under which the space is complete. Minkowski space incorporates three dimensional space together with a time dimension. It comes with a Lorentzian inner product which is not an inner product (it is not positive definite). When one says 'Minkowski space' one usually means the geometry of the space with the Lorentzian inner product. Therefore, no, Minkowski space is not a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 2):

No. In Minkowski space we have a bilinear form$$\bigl\langle(t,x,y,z),(t',x',y',z')\bigr\rangle=-tt'+xx'+yy'+zz'$$which is *not* an inner product. Therefore, it doesn't induce a metric.

Comment: So you assume that Minkowski space is $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: @Filippo Indeed. As the Wikipedia article about the Minkowski space says, “Minkowski space (…) is a combination of three-dimensional Euclidean space and time into a four-dimensional manifold where the spacetime interval between any two events is independent of the inertial frame of reference in which they are recorded.”

Comment: In other words, you are saying that an event in spacetime - i.e. an element of Minkowski space $M$ - is a list of $4$ real numbers. Well, we can use a Minkowski chart to assign $4$ real numbers to each event (since a Minkowski chart is bijection from $M$ to $\mathbb R^4$), but there is no preferred chart and thus I wouldn't say that Minkowski space is $\mathbb R^4$. But I am open to a discussion.

Comment: @Filippo Well, I am not. I suggest that you post a question concerning this.